# How to round off data labels for a bar plot in geom_text in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, bar-chart

I'm making a series of bar charts where the percent value is placed above each bar. I'd like to round this to 0 decimal places, but it comes to 3 decimal place. Here's an example code I am using

```
g1 <- ggplot(mydata, aes(x=PF.Score))+
  geom_bar(color="Blue", fill="skyblue")+
  geom_text(stat="count", aes(label=scales::percent(..prop..), group=1), size =3, vjust=-0.3)+
  ylab("Count of Suppliers")+
  xlab("D&B Score of Suppliers")+
  ggtitle("D&B Score distribution of suppliers")+
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

Is there a way to round these to the nearest whole number, so that the bars are labelled with no decimal?

Comment: @John J, I think you can help me out in this

Comment: round(mydata$PF.Score, digits = 0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `accuracy = 1` within `scales::percent` function like

```
ggplot(iris, aes(x=Sepal.Width))+
  geom_bar(color="Blue", fill="skyblue")+
  geom_text(stat="count", aes(label=scales::percent(..prop.., accuracy = 1), group=1), size =3, vjust=-0.3)+
  ylab("Count of Suppliers")+
  xlab("D&B Score of Suppliers")+
  ggtitle("D&B Score distribution of suppliers")+
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

To have 1 or 2 decimals you can use `accuracy = 0.1` or `accuracy = 0.01`. For details visit [this](https://scales.r-lib.org/reference/label_percent.html).

Comment: ......Sorry to bother you mate.......I have one more query.....if you see the image on right hand side...the y axis scale is same but the height of bar is different....eg. in case of electrical 47% is less than 28% bar of powertrain.....will you please help where i am doing wrong

Comment: I need the data to see the exact problem. You can try `scales = "free"` withing `facet` function.

Answer (score 0):

Your y axis is count, but your bar label is percentages. That is why they don’t match.